# Can I convert image to PDF/A document using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, itext

i want to convert images to pdf using itextsharp.
but i want the resultant pdf in PDF/A Standard..
please help me..

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

See [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=226) on how to generate PDF/A compliant files with iText.

Even though this example is in Java, the conversion to C# should be straightforward.